# How configure mysql for a heavy load ajax application which is using tomcat connection pooling?

Tags: mysql, ajax, database-connection, innodb

I've a GWT ajax application on tomcat server 7 which uses connection pooling to interact with its back-end mysql 5 database (My database only contains InnoDB tables).
The application is extremely based on db operations & for each little operation it need to fetch some data or write data from/to db, call db SPs & user-defined functions & so on...
The program will use each connection for a short time & then will return it to connection pool. the maximum concurrent connections may increase about 100-200 connections at the pick load time.
It works fine at the beginning of running mysql server, but after one or two hours, it became too slow & the number of failed connections to database increases about 10% off all connections.
I've tried to use my-large or my-huge default suggested configurations of mysql server, but I think i need something more than these to achieve a stable situation for mysql server.
any idea ?

Comment: What is your max connections set to? Mysql can handle a lot of connections, 100-200 is fairly low. Try 800 or 1000, I've seen even higher than that.

Comment: max connections parameter is large enough & I'm sure this does not causes the problem

Comment: why are the connections failing then? Are they timing out?

Comment: this is same I want to know. I don't think they time out, but I've no idea about source of problem